# ionic 2 e2e testing is not working when i integrate to my app

Tags: ionic2, e2e-testing

I used this link and that clicker app runs good and testing works fine when i try to integrate it to my app i get this err

http://lathonez.github.io/2016/ionic-2-unit-testing/

```
yokeshs-Mac-mini:easycloud yokesh$ node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile test/gulpfile.ts --cwd ./ unit-test
[12:25:10] Requiring external module ts-node/register
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
gulpfile.ts (1,69): Cannot find module './config'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (3,31): Cannot find module 'del'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (5,31): Cannot find module 'glob'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (6,31): Cannot find module 'gulp'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (7,31): Cannot find module 'istanbul'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (8,31): Cannot find module 'karma'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (9,31): Cannot find module 'gulp-load-plugins'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (10,31): Cannot find module 'run-sequence'. (2307)
test/gulpfile.ts (3,31): Cannot find module 'del'. (2307)
test/gulpfile.ts (5,31): Cannot find module 'glob'. (2307)
test/gulpfile.ts (6,31): Cannot find module 'gulp'. (2307)
test/gulpfile.ts (7,31): Cannot find module 'istanbul'. (2307)
test/gulpfile.ts (8,31): Cannot find module 'karma'. (2307)
test/gulpfile.ts (9,31): Cannot find module 'gulp-load-plugins'. (2307)
test/gulpfile.ts (10,31): Cannot find module 'run-sequence'. (2307)
    at getOutput (/Users/yokesh/easycloud/node_modules/ts-node/src/ts-node.ts:210:13)
    at Object.loader (/Users/yokesh/easycloud/node_modules/ts-node/src/ts-node.ts:225:23)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/Users/yokesh/easycloud/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/Users/yokesh/easycloud/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:193:16)
    at module.exports (/Users/yokesh/easycloud/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/Users/yokesh/easyc
```